# ¿Desde cuándo y dónde se usa "diálogo de besugos" para referirse a una conversación sin coherencia lógica?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, diferencias-regionales, historia, animales

En el Diccionario de la lengua española he encontrado que `diálogo de besugos` es

> [diálogo de besugos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DetWqMJ)
>   1. m. coloq. Conversación sin coherencia lógica.

Buscando la explicación a esta expresión he visto que una de las acepciones de `besugo` desde 1983 (en la edición actual, la segunda acepción) es:

> [besugo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5Pun2wp)
>   2. m. Persona torpe o necia.

Lo que parece aclarar la expresión: es fácil suponer que una conversación entre personas torpes o necias carezca de coherencia lógica.

Sin embargo, no he podido encontrar ningún ejemplo en el CORDE o en el CREA de uso de esta expresión, y la acepción de `besugo = persona torpe o necia` es muy reciente [1983 en el DLE], lo que me hace preguntar:

- ¿Desde cuándo se usa esta expresión?
- **¿Se utiliza habitualmente / se entiende en todo el mundo hispanoparlante?**

Answer (score 5):

Sí, la expresión *diálogo de besugos* es muy reciente, se añadió al diccionario de la RAE en 2001, aunque a mí me da la sensación de que es bastante anterior. La explicación, como afirmas, es que la acepción de *besugo* como "hombre torpe y necio" es también bastante reciente.

Antes se usaban otras expresiones mucho más directas:

> *—Parece un diálogo de idiotas —dijo Traveler.
>
>   —De mongoloides puros —dijo Oliveira.
>
>   —Uno cree que va a explicar algo, y cada vez es peor.*
>
> Julio Cortázar, "Rayuela", 1963 (Argentina).

Es cierto que en el CORDE no existen casos de la expresión, pero sí que los hay en el CREA. El más antiguo es este:

> *Si se piensa que por aquellas fechas Rusia y Occidente no se ponían de acuerdo sobre si la España de Franco constituía un peligro real o potencial para la paz internacional, se comprende que toda la historia de las negociaciones de desarme haya sido una comedia de despropósitos, una pieza de teatro de lo absurdo o, como decían los humoristas de la España autárquica, un interminable diálogo de besugos.*
>
> Aquilino Duque, "El suicidio de la modernidad. Una revisión crítica de
>   la cultura contemporánea", 1984 (España).

Este texto además nos informa de que la expresión *diálogo de besugos* se originó en España durante la dictadura de Franco. De hecho en la hemeroteca de la BNE los primeros casos se ven en textos de 1971 (aunque corresponden con ejemplares cuyo acceso es de pago), y en la hemeroteca del ABC hay un caso de 1965:

> *El diálogo de los sordos continúa, aunque es posible que sea seguido del diálogo para besugos.*
>
> ABC SEVILLA, 20/05/1965, página 63.

Y es que en realidad la acepción despectiva de *besugo* viene de mucho antes:

> *Ya se sabe hacia qué época se abrirán las Cortes.
>
>   ¡Hacia Diciembre!
>
>   El mes tradicional del turrón y el besugo.
>
>   Y como ustedes saben, no se trata de otra cosa.
>
>   De que los besugos se coman los turrones.
>
>   Y á nosotros nos dan la lata.
>
>   Pero vacía.*
>
> Blanco y Negro (Madrid), 30/10/1892, página 15.

Curioso que al principio la acepción despectiva de *besugo* al principio parecía aplicarse únicamente a la clase política:

> *Ocurre en esto lo que en política. En vano queremos prescindir de los besugos politicantes* vieux jeu, *si no nos hemos preocupado antes de formar otros nuevos.*
>
> ABC (Madrid), 08/11/1917, página 6.

Si los *besugos* solían ser políticos, y los políticos son personas que suelen pasar mucho tiempo dialogando en las Cortes, la creación de la expresión *diálogo de besugos* era cuestión de tiempo.

Con respecto a si se entiende en todo el mundo hispanohablante, los ejemplos que he encontrado son todos de España. En el *Diccionario de americanismos* aparece la palabra *besugo* pero solo con su acepción referente al pez. Eso parece descartar que se use allí esta palabra de forma despectiva de la misma manera que en España, aunque sí que hay un caso en el CREA:

> *Mariano Gómez de Liaño salió como una flecha hacia el juez García-Castellón, que aún no había bajado del estrado. El fiscal Orti se aproximó y Jiménez fue detrás suyo. Gómez de Liaño levantó el dedo índice de su mano izquierda, señaló hacia la puerta del tribunal. Todavía le quedaban agallas para amenazar. García-Castellón puso cara de besugo.*
>
> Ernesto Ekaizer, "Vendetta", 1996 (Argentina).

No estoy seguro en todo caso de cuál es la intención del escritor en este fragmento. Hay uno mucho más claro, aunque es algo antiguo:

> *Claro, al lado de don Olimpio, que es un besugo, eres una lumbrera; pero al lado de las lumbreras, eres menos que un fósforo.*
>
> Emilio Bobadilla, "A fuego lento", 1903 (Cuba).

Ya es cuestión de que nuestros compañeros americanos nos confirmen si se usa *besugo* como insulto en los países de allí, y si es así si la expresión *diálogo de besugos* se entendería.

Answer (score 3):

El escritor Armando Matías Guiu ya escribía en en los años 50 sus Diálogos para Besugos que aparecían en la revistas comicas DDT y TBO (escribo de memoria) También hay un libro homónimo que recoge esos diálogos.